# Saxon XSLT2.0 Extracting Numbers from the String

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to Extract Integer from a String using Xslt2.0
For Example consider the string "designa80000dd5424d" and i need the two integers inside the string i.e "8000" and "5424"

I tried using translate function as below

select="translate($term,translate($term, '0123456789', ''), '')"

But it combines both the integers and gives the output as "80005424"
i need something which separates them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using translate function as below
>
> select="translate($term,translate($term, '0123456789', ''), '')"
>
> But it combines both the numbers and gives the output as "80005424" i
>   need something which separates them

**I. Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="vSpaces">
      <xsl:call-template name="makeSpaces"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vtheNumbers" 
         select="normalize-space(translate(., translate(.,'0123456789',''), $vSpaces))"/>

    <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
      <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="$vtheNumbers"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="pStr"/>
    <xsl:param name="pInd" select="1"/>

    <xsl:if test="string-length($pStr)">
      <xsl:value-of select=
           "concat($pInd, ': ',substring-before(concat($pStr, ' '), ' '), '&#xA;')"/>

      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="substring-after($pStr, ' ')"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pInd" select="$pInd +1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="makeSpaces">
    <xsl:param name="pLen" select="string-length(.)"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$pLen = 1">
        <xsl:value-of select="' '"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$pLen > 1">
        <xsl:variable name="vHalfLen" select="floor($pLen div 2)"/>

        <xsl:call-template name="makeSpaces">
          <xsl:with-param name="pLen" select="$vHalfLen"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="makeSpaces">
          <xsl:with-param name="pLen" select="$pLen -$vHalfLen"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>designa80000dd5424dan1733g122</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
1: 80000
2: 5424
3: 1733
4: 122
```

**Do note**:

The last argument of the outer `translate()` is a string having the same number of characters as that of the input string, and each of these characters is a space.

---

**II. XPath 2.0 shorter and simpler**

This XPath 2.0 expression when evaluated produces the wanted sequence of numbers:

```
tokenize(., '[^\d]+')[.]
```

**Here is an XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:variable name="vNumbers" 
    select="tokenize(., '[^\d]+')[.]"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="$vNumbers">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ': ', ., '&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document**:

```
<t>designa80000dd5424dan1733g122</t>
```

**the same correct result is produced**:

```
1: 80000
2: 5424
3: 1733
4: 122
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @dimitre but i cannot guarantee that there will be only two numbers in a string there might be 'N' number of Numbers in one String. In Above solution it is Restricted to t Numbers

Comment: @premkumar: In XSLT 2.0 one can immediately get the N substrings separated by whitespace using the standard XPath 2.0 function `tokenize()` . There are also XSLT 1.0 solutions (see for example the FXSL `tokenize()` function). that you may search for. And if you are "new to this XSLT" as you say in another comment, it would be more appropriate to start with more basic concepts and try to gain solid understanding.

Comment: @premkumar, I updated the solution and now it can retrieve and process any number of numbers in the input string.

Comment: This Solution is working @DImitre . I would definitely like to upvote your answer but due to my reputation i am not able to :(

Answer (score 1):

You could try it using `tokenize` with any non-digit sequences as the separator, i.e. using XPath 3.0 `tokenize('designa80000dd5424d', '[^0-9]+')[normalize-space()]!number()` or in XSLT/XPath 2.0 as `for $t in tokenize('designa80000dd5424d', '[^0-9]+')[normalize-space()] return number($t)` or you could use `xsl:analyze-string` (XSLT 2.0) or the `analyze-string` function (XSLT/XPath 3.0, but available with Saxon 9.7 HE).

Comment: i am using plain XSL file to convert xml to String so i can not return any value form the function can you please elaborate on the solution

Comment: Does `<xsl:value-of select="for $t in tokenize($term, '[^0-9]+')[normalize-space()] return number($t)"/>` not work?  I can only elaborate on the code if you show us some context or explain what kind of result (e.g. a sequence of two numbers or a string with two numbers separator by some space) you want.

Comment: @premkumar, I don't understand what you mean by your comment. What do you mean when you say you cannot return any value from the function (which function?). You can always return a value from a function.

Comment: @MichaelKay I am new to this XSLT, In above solution of martin he is saying to rerturn number($t) using XPATH2.0 but i am saying i dont write any functions to return a value i am just writing templates

Comment: @premkumar, `for $t in tokenize('designa80000dd5424d', '[^0-9]+')[normalize-space()] return number($t)` is a simple XPath 2.0 expression giving a sequence of number values, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions. It has nothing to do with functions or returning a value from a function.